# how to print the number of times code looped?

Tags: c

i have wrote a simple code that prints all the prime numbers from the number that has entered. I would like to print how many prime numbers are printed. I think its print("%d",c++); but i dont know where to put it. I have tried putting it right before return 0; at the end of prime method but it does not work. The prime numbers print just fine but the counter does not print.

```
    void main(void){
        int pri;
        scan("%d",&pri);
        prime(pri);    
    }

    void prime(int n){
        int m,i,c,x;

        for(m = 1;m<=n;m++){
            c = 0;
            for(i=2;i<=m/2;i++){
                if(m%i==0){
                    c++;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if(c==0 && m!= 1){
                printf("%d ",m);
            }          
        }  
        print("the count is: ");              
        print("%d",c);        
        return 0;


    }
```

If I input 100 I want the output to be:

```
 2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 
 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
 The count is 25.
```

Comment: `print` should be `printf`.

Comment: And `scan` should be `scanf`. Aren't you getting errors when you compile the program?

Comment: You don't want `print` do you?  It should be `printf`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah is there an echo in here?

Comment: no it does not. I am running it on SimpleIDE. I do not get error for scan nor print.

Comment: "The counter does not print" means you don't see the line `the count is`? Then print a newline after the number. (Also, look up basic `printf` formatting.)

Comment: Splitting your function in sub functions would help: `int count = 0; for (int i = 0; i <= n; +n) { if (is_prime(i)) {++count; printf("%d ",m); } } printf("the count is: %d", count);`

Answer (score 0):

Add a variable `count` since `c` is not your count. It is a local test variable whether a prime has been found. add `int count = 0;` in front of the for loop and print it instead of `c` at the end. In the if statement where you print the single primes, add `count++;`.

```
int n = 100; // for copy paste purposes

int m,i,c,x;
int count = 0;

for(m = 1;m<=n;m++){
    //c = 0;
    for(i=2;i<=m/2;i++){
        if(m%i==0){
            c++;
            break;
        }
    }

    if(c==0 && m!= 1){
        printf("%d ",m);
        count++;
    }
}
printf("\nthe count is: %d\n", count);
```

Comment: Thank you!!! it worked! Im sorry guys for the noob question. I am very new to programming. For some reason on SimpleIDE, i have to use print instead of printf....else it wont print properly. My class is learning  from this site. http://learn.parallax.com/propeller-c-functions/function-parameter. In that example it uses print and not printf.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few things your program should take care of most importantly it should compile first which I highly doubt it does at this point.Anyway below is a working example for it, with modifications

```
#include <stdio.h>

void prime(int ); // prototype

//void main(void){
int main(void){
    int pri;
    //scan("%d",&pri);
    scanf("%d",&pri);
    prime(pri);    
    return 0;
}

void prime(int n)
{
    int m,i,c,count = 0; // your counter

    for(m = 1 ; m <= n ; m++ ) {
        c = 0;

        for( i = 2 ; i <= m/2 ; i++ ) {

            if( m%i == 0 ) {
                c++;
                break;
            }
        }

        if( c == 0 && m != 1 ){
               printf("%d ",m);
               count = count + 1;   // keep counting
        }
    }  
    //print("the count is: ");              
    printf("\nthe count is: ");              
    //print("%d",c);        
    printf("%d",count);        
    //  return 0;


}
```

Note - better formatting the key.